# Help! Can you get my puzzle back?

Tags: grid-deduction, word-search

Puzzling has a lot of really complicated stuff these days, so I just wanted to post a simple Boggle grid.

You know that game, right? You form words by starting from one letter, then taking adjacent letters moving in any of the eight directions, but you can't use the same letter twice to form a single word.

Here are the words you are looking for, they should be familiar to most of you:

> [time](/questions/tagged/time) [termination](/questions/tagged/termination) [tetris](/questions/tagged/tetris) [nim](/questions/tagged/nim) [animals](/questions/tagged/animals) [real](/questions/tagged/real) [tangram](/questions/tagged/tangram) [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) [pangram](/questions/tagged/pangram) [game](/questions/tagged/game) [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram) [flags](/questions/tagged/flags) [nonogram](/questions/tagged/nonogram)

And here is the grid:

[image]

Um... that was not what the grid was supposed to look like at all! Have I got one of those newfangled viruses or something?

Since we're already here, can you help me recover my puzzle? I didn't take any backups while I was making this, and I'm really desperate to remember what it was like!

---

<sup>Luckily, the virus or whatever it was seems to have picked colorblind-friendly colors for the image, but if that somehow is still an issue here is a text transcription, in which different letters represent different colors:</sup>

```
ABCBB
CDEFG
HGABI
JKGGC
LMFMF
```

Comment: As a confused colourblind person. Are you saying that the letters are written on the grid ? Because I can't see a thing

Comment: @user3660570 Each letter corresponds to a different color on the image. The image doesn't have any letters.

Comment: You don't really need "nim" if you have "animals", right? (That is, "nim" gives no extra information if I understand correctly.)

Comment: No, you don't. I just liked the extra free tag.

Comment: I assume the puzzle uses standard Boggle rules?

Comment: @Forklift are there any rules other than the ones I listed? All 8 directions, and you can't repeat squares for a single word.

Comment: The Wikipedia rules section was startlingly long, just covering my bases :)

Comment: @ffao I like this puzzle, I think will make similar puzzle like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer:

> `rtitt`
>  `imena`
>  `sartp`
>  `lgaai`
>  `fonon`

Explanation:

Here's the initial grid:

```
ABCBB
CDEFG
HGABI
JKGGC
LMFMF
```

> Start by counting the number of occurrences of each colour (which I'll represent using capital letters):
>
> - `A`×2, `B`×4, `C`×3, `D`×1, `E`×1, `F`×3, `G`×4, `H`×1, `I`×1, `J`×1, `K`×1, `L`×1, `M`×2
>
> and the minimum number of times we know each letter occurs in the final grid (I'll use lowercase letters for the letters in the eventual grid):
>
> - `a`×3 (`anagram`), `i`×2 (`termination`), `n`×2 (`termination`), `o`×2 (`nonogram`), `t`×2 (`pattern`), other letters could appear once
>
> There are a total of thirteen letters in the tags (`aefgilmnoptrs`), and thirteen colours on the grid, so there must be a 1-to-1 correspondence.
>
> I started off by looking at `t`, `o`, and `n`. `t` must clearly be `B` or `G`, as no other colour allows for the adjacent `t`s in `pattern`. Looking at all the places we could possibly spell `nono` (from `nonogram`), they must either be in `B` and `C` (some way round), or else two of `F`/`G`/`M`.
>
> The next letter to check was `a`. The requirement to spell `anagram` means we can't have `a`=`C` (which would force `n` into `B` with `a` as `C`, or into `D` which isn't a valid location for it). We also can't have `a`=`F`, as that quickly leads to a contradiction:
>
> ```
> ABgBB    ABgBB
> gDmao    gDman
> HoABr or HnABr
> JKoog    JKnng
> Lnana    Loaoa
> ```
>
> In other words, we've found our first letter position, `a`=`G` (immediately forcing `t`=`B` to spell `pattern`).
>
> ```
> AtCtt
> CDEFa
> HaAtI
> JKaaC
> LMFMF
> ```
>
> `no` now must be `MF` (one way round or the other). This means that `p`=`I`:
>
> ```
> AtCtt
> CDEFa
> HaAtp
> JKaaC
> LMFMF
> ```
>
> If `M`=`n`, then we can't spell `pangram`. Thus, `F`=`n` and `M`=`o`:
>
> ```
> AtCtt
> CDEna
> HaAtp
> JKaaC
> Lonon
> ```
>
> To be able to spell `nonogram`, `anagram`, *and* `pangram`, we need `K`=`g`:
>
> ```
> AtCtt
> CDEna
> HaAtp
> JgaaC
> Lonon
> ```
>
> To spell `termination`, we need `C`=`i`:
>
> ```
> Atitt
> iDEna
> HaAtp
> Jgaai
> Lonon
> ```
>
> and `ADE` need to spell `erm` in some order (for `termination`); to be able to fit `tetris` in too we need `A`=`r`, `E`=`e`, `H`=`s`:
>
> ```
> rtitt
> imena
> sartp
> Jgaai
> Lonon
> ```
>
> `animals` requires `J`=`l`, `flags` requires `L`=`f`:
>
> ```
> rtitt
> imena
> sartp
> lgaai
> fonon
> ```

We can find all the words in this grid, so we know it's correct.